# ValueError: row index exceeds matrix dimensions sparse coo max

Tags: python, dataframe, sparse-matrix

I really have no idea what's the root cause! I have created below matrix and had tried increase the (M, N) size, or reduce the data size or the row size or column size or even change the dtype from float32 to float64, but all fails! I keep getting 'row index exceeds matrix dimensions' errow, please help if you have any clues, thank you.

```
adj = sp.coo_matrix((np.ones(edges.shape[0]), (edges[:, 0],edges[:, 1])),
                      shape=(np.max(node_labels.shape[0])+1, np.max(node_labels.shape[0])+1), dtype=np.float32)
```

Besides,

> len(np.ones(edges.shape[0])) = len(edges[:, 0]) = len(edges[:, 1])=
> 1432000

and

> len(node_labels.shape[0]) = 1432002

> np.max(node_labels.shape[0])+1 = 1432003

You may have already found that, my "edges" size is much lower than my "node_labels" size, how come i still get row index exceed error???

Comment: What's the max of `edges`?

Comment: please see my question, max of edges is len(edges.shape[0]) = 1432000

Comment: actually it's 1432002, but i have removed last two rows to prevent row index=shape(M,N), however, no use.

Comment: Shape has to be larger than the maximum index value.  Often you can omit the shape specification, allowing it to deduce the shape from the indices.

Answer (score 1):

I had solved the problem myself, well, the truth is quite cruel, just need to re encode the values in edges[:, 0]) and edges[:, 1], however, i have no idea how it will affect my gcn model as i only encode columns of edge.csv leaving nodes.csv unchanged...